# how to export data from one excel spreadsheet to another automatically at certain time

Tags: excel, ssis

**Overview:**

A system sends outbound excel file in a folder and picks inbound excel file from different folder every day at the certain time. Both the inbound and outbound files have different column headers. I want to do data migration from outbound file to inbound file.

**Problem**:

I cannot figure out how to send data from one excel file (outbound) to another excel file (inbound) at the certain time of the day (before system picks inbound file) automatically.

Secondly, column headers are different for instance in both files.

**Analogy:**

Everyday At 2am

I want to data transfer:
A.xlsx -> B.xlsx

from Column ***fName*** in A.xlsx to ***FirstName*** in B.xlsx

Kindly advise step by step instruction of whatever the method you recommend.
I think that can be achieved through SSIS but not sure how to achieve.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a *specific* problem after trying to solve it on their own. If, after **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)**, you have a *specific* problem, please [edit] your post to share [examples of your code and relevant data](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some background info. Some good reading to get you started: "[ask]" as well as tips **[here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and **[here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot figure out how to send data from one excel file (outbound) to
>   another excel file (inbound) at the certain time of the day (before
>   system picks inbound file) automatically.

The best way to perform some action, such as launching an SSIS package, at a certain time of day is with a [SQL Agent Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: or just disable the data flow task using expression to compare with the current time